# spliting a decimal values to lower decimal in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How can i split a  decimal value into two decimal values.
if the decimal number which has fractional part that is less than .50 or greater than .50 .it should split in such a way that first no should end with only .00 or .50. second value should contain the remaining factorial value.

```
ex.  19.97 should return 19.50 & 0.47
     19.47               19.00 & 0.47
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can "floor" to the highest multiple of 0.5 by multiplying by 2, calling `FLOOR`, then dividing by 2.  From there just subtract that from the original value to get the remainder.

```
DECLARE @test decimal(10,7)
SELECT @test =19.97

SELECT 
    FLOOR(@test * 2) / 2 AS base, 
    @test - FLOOR(@test * 2) / 2 AS fraction
```

or to reduce duplication

```
SELECT 
    base, 
    @test - base AS fraction
FROM ( SELECT FLOOR(@test * 2) / 2 AS base )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Declare @money money

Set @money = 19.97

Select  convert(int,@money - (@money % 1))  as 'LeftPortion'
       ,convert(int, (@money % 1) * 100)    as 'RightPortion'
```

Answer (score 1):

Observe that doubling `0.5` gives `1`, which is a whole number. This leads to a simple algorithm:

- Double the number
- Split it into a whole and a fractional parts by using `floor(x)` and `x-floor(x)`
- Divide each part separately by 2 to give you the results that you need.

Let's take your numbers as an example:

```
19.97 * 2 = 39.94
Whole part = 39, fractional part = 0.94
Dividing each part by 2 individually, we get
39/2 = 19.50
0.94/2 = 0.47

19.47 * 2 = 38.94
Whole part = 38, fractional part = 0.94
Dividing each part by 2 individually, we get
38/2 = 19.00
0.94/2 = 0.47
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to look into the [`MODULO` operator in SQL Server.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190279%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)

```
SELECT 
19.97 as myDecVal , 
19.97 % 0.5 AS decGreaterThan50,/*should return 0.47*/ 
19.97- (19.97 % 0.5) as roundedToNearestZeroPoint5 /*should return 19.50*/;
```

Comment: @DStanley: Are you sure? The link I've given suggests otherwise: "The modulo arithmetic operator can be used in the select list of the SELECT statement with any combination of column names, numeric constants, or any valid expression of the integer and monetary data type categories or the numeric data type." See SQLFiddle demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/23960

Comment: You are correct - I was thinking I had tried that for something else recently and it didn't work.  I've deleted my comment.